# Postgres - could not create any TCP/IP sockets

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a rails app in development with postgresql 9.3. When I tried to start passenger server today, I got:

```
PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (217.74.65.145) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

No big deal I thought, that happened before. Restarting postgres always solved the problem. So I ran `sudo service postgresql restart` and got:

```
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2014-06-11 10:32:41 CEST LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Cannot assign requested address
2014-06-11 10:32:41 CEST HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2014-06-11 10:32:41 CEST WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2014-06-11 10:32:41 CEST FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
...fail!
```

My `postgresql.conf` points to the defaults: `localhost` and port `5432`. I tried changing the port but the error message is the same (except the port change).

Both `ps aux | grep postgresql` and `ps aux | grep postmaster` return nothing.

**EDIT:**

In `postgresql.conf` I changed `listen_addresses` to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and it did the trick, server restarted. I also had to edit my applications' db config and point to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. However, the question is now, why is localhost considered to be `217.74.65.145` and not `127.0.0.1`?

That's my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   local
127.0.1.1   jacek-X501A1
127.0.0.1   something.name.non.example.com
127.0.0.1   company.something.name.non.example.com
```

Comment: any output from `sudo netstat -anlp | grep 5432`?

Comment: If you're going to obfuscate your data, please do so responsibly and use `example.com` as the domain name.

Comment: I was getting similar error when that port was blocked by a docker container.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `/etc/hosts` is broken. The first line should read

```
127.0.0.1   localhost something.name.non.example.com company.something.name.non.example.com
```

Comment: Note for future readers that even if you *do* have a localhost entry in `/etc/hosts`, various other factors can cause a different DNS response when a DNS lookup of `localhost` is actually run.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47824848/5419599.

Comment: @Wildcard I do not know which OS that answer would be applicable to (if any). It certainly doesn't make much sense on Linux.

Comment: @kasperd I suppose if you've got the order `dns files` instead of `files dns` in nsswitch.conf, **and** have a name server that resolves localhost, you could get in trouble. But that does sound highly unlikely to me...

Comment: @JennyD The answer linked above suggests using `nslookup` to verify. But the `nslookup` command on Linux doesn't use `nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/hosts` in the first place. And as for putting `dns files` in the configuration, that sounds like asking for trouble to me.

Comment: @kasperd Agreed - it would be fairly high on the "it's-your-own-damned-fault" scale...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is answered, but for those who still have the error, the reason could be is that some other process has already started it. 
For example `Homebrew` on system boot.

If that's the case try to stop it: 
`brew services stop postgres`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the listening address of Postgres: it was configured to listen on its own IP (not 'localhost') on the network it was probably connected to when installed.

Anyway, open `postgresql.conf` and make sure `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` (or something else meaningful to you).